# Howto layout div contents to i) horizontally line up and ii) child stretches to parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've gotten the #right-col to take the screen's remaining width from #left-col is set to 500px (or whatever).

What I'm trying to find, is a way to make #entries, #entry and #entry-part do 2 things at once: i) take the entire width of #right-col (#right-wrapper is also same width), even on a window resize, while at the same time, ii) horizontally lining them up side by side so that iii) other divs stretch out the #right-content and are hidden on the right behind #right-wrapper.

I've obviously looked at similar posts. But my problem seems to be that the #right-col is float:right. I've set up [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/jh2qE/1/) to illustrate the problem.

```
    #right-col
      #right-wrapper
        #right-content
          #entries
          #entry 
          #entry-part
```

For some reason, I can' reach these 3 goals. Any help on this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should add your HTML or put it in a fiddle. Just makes it easier for people to help you out. :D

Comment: Dear fiddle is already add please see above the code.

Comment: Your problem is interesting and bit confusing also. what you gave in fiddle is very messed up. its taking too much time to understand your code and css too.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can simplify...

Comment: Ok, so I've update [the jsFiddle to this](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/jh2qE/5/), and pared down the HTML to just the essentials. HTH, and thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

The display:box (Its not in w3c nor mozilla doc, does it really exist?) seems to cause the trouble.

see here :  http://jsfiddle.net/jh2qE/9/
(I only commented out some css in #main-content)

Here's a few tips to remember :

- position:absolute take your element out of context, so

  `<div style="width:100%><div style="width:100%;position:absolute">content</div></div>`

  (yes,inline css is bad)
  In this example, the inner div would only take what's needed for the content to be   display (as in, not large at all).
- float:*side* doesn't take space in a parent element if you do not clear it

  `<div style="min-height:1em"><div style="float:left;height:1000px">stuff</div></div>`

  The parent div here will have only 1em in height, not 1000px.
- display:block elements take 100% of the container width by default.

That should do­.

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to obtain although.
A picture of what you want could validate (or invalidate) my answer.